# PostgresSQL is not getting connected

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Ubuntu operating system and trying to install postgresSQL in my system.
After completing the installation and entering postgres mode when I enter the command pgsql, it gives me this error

psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

what could possibly be wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Probably the postgresql server is not running; you can run `netstat -adp` to see if postgres is listening on port 5432.

If it isn't, then it most likely isn't running; `systemctl status postgresql` will help identify if it is even installed, and if it has run into any issues (for further details, see https://mydbanotebook.org/post/troubleshooting-01/)

If it is running and seems healthy, then it might not be configured to accept connections in whichever way you are connecting (which user, database, host/network etc) - see details about the `pg_hba.conf` file that includes rules for this - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: as suggested by the documentation, i checked the running status with command,  "pgrep -u postgres -fa -- -D", and found postgres was not running, then I run "pg_ctlcluster 13 main start" command and got following error "Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 383."

Answer (score 0):

After install, you must create an instance with initdb.
Later, change the listen_address to *, restart the service and now you can check the port.
Check the pg log for the message: "postgres is ready to accept connections"